# Fading Image Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm trying to fade images in and out of each other. I'm not sure if it's better to preload the image before hand or not. Pretty much what's happening is that fade is hitting completely white background before fading in the next image, but I want it to fade immediatly instead of showing the white background - if that makes sense:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $next, 
        cycle;
    var i = 0;
    var imgArr = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg'];

    $activeLi = $("#slideshow li");
    $activeLi.html('<img src="images/' + imgArr[i] + '" />');
    cycle = setInterval(change_img, 1000);

    function change_img(){
        clearInterval(cycle);
        $activeLi.find('img').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $activeLi.html('<img src="images/' + imgArr[i] + '" />').fadeIn('slow');
        });

        i = (i == (imgArr.length - 1)) ? 0 : ++i;
        cycle = setInterval(change_img, 1000);
    }
});
```

Also is it better to prealod my images before fading them in?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/De63Q/)

**My Solution** (Which is jaded sinced I started the question...)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $next, 
        cycle;
    var i = 0;
    var durTimer = 2000;
    var imgArr = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg'];

    $activeLi = $("#slideshow li");
    $activeLi.first().html('<img src="images/' + imgArr[0] + '" />');
    cycle = setInterval(change_img, durTimer);

    function change_img(){
        clearInterval(cycle);
        var nxtImg = (i == imgArr.length) ? 1 : i;
        $activeLi.last().html('<img src="images/' + imgArr[nxtImg] + '" />');
        $activeLi.find('img').animate({opacity:0}, {duration: durTimer});   

        i = (i == (imgArr.length - 1)) ? 0 : ++i;
        $activeLi.first().html('<img src="images/' + imgArr[i] + '" />');
        cycle = setInterval(change_img, durTimer);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd love to help, do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: It doesn't have the images I guess, but the gist of it is there... http://jsfiddle.net/De63Q/

Comment: It is better to preload (unless you have *tiny* images), because then the first image can be displayed while the rest download, and at the time of their use, the request only needs to verify a 304 status (not modified), which is much quicker than downloading. It would slow down your fade/slideshow the first run through, but could mean saving a few seconds per picture. For avoiding the whitespace, you probably want to overlap `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` by a portion of their runtimes.

Comment: So you don't want it to fade all the way out before the next one?  What if, instead of fadeOut, you used .animate() with the opacity down to 0.20 or so, then switched out images, then .animate() back up to 1.0 opactiy. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: @Seano666 I tried messing around with animate() but couldn't get it to work properly, I'll keep messing around with it though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have limited number of images, it is better to load all of them on page load.

In the given example, you are using only one `img` tag and changing the source of that to another image after some time.

So, when the image is faded out, definitely we can see the white background. Also it will take some time to load the new image.

1. Instead of a single img tag, add three img tags (from your code, there are three images).
2. Start both the `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` animations at a time.
3. `fadeOut` for current image and `fadeIn` for next image.

This will not show any white background.

I already created a small demo for this.

Check this out : http://db.tt/q8VPb03U

Comment: Well the array is eventually going to be dynamic, so instead of 1 image I would have to replace 3 images with different images from teh array.

Comment: Don't replace any images. On the page load itself add three images. But style them to show all the three images one on one (give some position). Then you just need to fadeOut one and fadeIn other. No need to change `src` attribute of any image.